# keydown event fire only once when i press the j key

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a **div** which animate only once when I press the **j** button, I want to animate the **div** each time when i press **j** button on my keyboard without refreshing the page.

is this possible using JQuery???

sorry for my bad english.

following is my code.

**animate.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
    .div {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes example {
        0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
        50%  {background-color:green; left:100px; top:100px;}
        100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    }

    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes example {
        0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
        50%  {background-color:yellow; left:100px; top:100px;}
        100%  {background-color:yellow; left:0px; top:0px;}

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>
        <b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.
    </p>
    <br>
    <div id="box"></div>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).bind('keydown', 'j', function(){
            $('#box').addClass("div");
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats in your hotkeys js? can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remove the class each time and add class again to you `div`, here is the fiddle -
http://jsfiddle.net/hwu1z7dh/1/

Answer (score 1):

Jquery has replaced 'bind' by 'on'.

Try this code:

```
$('body').on('keydown',function(e){
  if(e.which==82 || e.which==106){
        $('#box').addClass("div");
  }
});
```

The ASCII value of 'J' is 82, and 'j' is 106.

Comment: add  a JSFiddle and we can try fix it

Comment: my bad, you need to set a timeout when the animation finish to remove the class

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem to me is that you aren't removing the `class=div` after the animation is over. In [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxk3jn8a/5/), I added an event that fires when the CSS animation ends:

```
//fires when 'j' key is pressed
$('body').on('keydown', function (e) {

    if (e.which == 106 || e.which == 74) {
        $('#box').addClass("div");
    }
});

$('#box').on('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
function (e) {
    $('#box').removeClass("div");
});
```

This code works for me in Chrome 44 and FireFox 39, but I just tested it in IE10, and it didn't seem to work at all. Didn't even want to fire the initial `keydown` event. I think the general idea is still true though. If you want the animation to repeat, you will have to remove the `.div` class after the animation ends, so that you can add it again on `keydown`.

**EDITED** fixed event to fire on 'j' not 'r' in my fiddle.

Comment: it works same like my code i.e, when i press j (in my case j=74) it animate only once but when again i press j button it didn't animate...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    if(key==74 || key==106){
    $('#box').addClass("div");
   }
 });
```